# Revtools: Load spanish characters in bibliographic data

Tags: r, encoding, locale, utf-16

I already have my locale to: `Spanish_Mexico.1252` and my encoding to `UTF-16LE` yet my data frame with the function `read_bibliography` ignores the characters in Spanish from Web of Science. There are no extra options for this function. Anyone has any experience in this package?

sample data:https://privfile.com/download.php?fid=62e01e7e95b08-MTQwMTc=

```
mydata <- revtools::read_bibliography("H:/Bibliométrico/Datos Bibliográficos/SCIELO/SCIQN220722.txt")

head(mydata$title)
    [1] "Metodologa de auditoria de marketing para servicios cientfico-tcnicos con enfoque de responsabilidad social empresarial"                       
    [2] "Contribucin a la competitividad de una empresa con herramientas estratgicas: Mtodo ABC y el personal de la organizacin"                        
    [3] "Quality tools and techniques, EFQM experience and strategy formation. Is there any relationship?: The particular case of Spanish service firms"
    [4] "Determinantes de las patentes y otras formas de propiedad intelectual de los estados mexicanos"                                                
    [5] "Modelos de clculo de las betas a aplicar en el Capital Asset Pricing Model: el caso de Argentina"                                              
    [6] "Mapas cognitivos difusos para la seleccin de proyectos de tecnologas de la informacin"
```

See how it ommits the latin charactes such as the **í** in **Metodología**, **Contribucn** instead of **Contribución**, etc.

Comment: Unclear what are you asking; moreover, your link is dead. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I fixed the link and I added an example, thank you.

Comment: The link says *expired*, sorry… Follow [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: Hi, fixed once again.